# Ionic HttpClient is sending a GET request instead of a POST

Tags: ionic-framework, cors, httpclient

I am trying to send a post request using HttpClient.

```js
constructor (private http: HttpClient) { }

this.http.post(url + 'auth/login', data).subscribe(res => { });
```

but the browser sends 4 requests instead of only one POST request:

- 2 OPTIONS requests
- 1 POST request
- 1 GET request

I have read that it's called "preflight request" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

I am getting a `405 Method Not Allowed` error because the server do not support GET requests for this path `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.`

Unfortianatilly, I cannot modify the server to accept GET requests, is there anyway that I can prevent the browser from sending a GET request?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that this happens only on "http://".

I have tried "https://" and it works correctly :)